# QT QSqlTableModel - background color in a given data column

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtgui

I have a tableView example:

[image]

Like when the data column  status is S.
The background color of the table would be green and when N would be red.

Example of what I want:

[image]

My code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
       //Con Db...

        model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
        model->setTable("app");
        model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
        model->select();
        model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("number"));
        model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("status"));
        ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reimplement, i.e. subclass `QSqlTableModel` and provide an implementation of the data function as per below. Note that the `MySubClassedSqlTableModel` implementation needs to be placed in a header file that is MOC'ed (normally automatically done).

```
  #include <QSqlTableModel>
    class MySubClassedSqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
           MySubClassedSqlTableModel(QObject * parent = 0, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
           : QSqlTableModel(parent,db) {;}
           QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
           {
              if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
              {
                 const QVariant value(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole));
                 return QVariant(QColor(value.toString()=="S"?Qt::green:Qt::red));
              }
              return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
           }
    };

    model = new MySubClassedSqlTableModel(this); //<==== use your model
            model->setTable("app");
            model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
            model->select();
            model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("number"));
            model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("status"));
            ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Btw subclassing is something you need to do in most cases when you want to customize the behavior.

Comment: @user628298: Haven't compiled it. Come back if it doesn't compile.

Comment: Erro: qvariant.h:480: error: 'QVariant::QVariant(Qt::GlobalColor)' is private
     QVariant(Qt::GlobalColor) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
     ^

Comment: @user628298: Fixed I hope.

Comment: How to increase the size of the table columns, you know? example: 300px each column, with 14px font.

Comment: This is not quite correct way, I think. As far as this feature is all about View, you'd better subclass QStyledItemDelegate and reimplement paint method.
After that you can apply you delegate to column with method
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(ColumnId, new QMyItemDelegate(this));